# C++ primer 5th edition: C++ template class arguments deduction

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

Again with C++ primer 5 edition chapter 16: Templates.

In the book:

"A class template is a blueprint for generating classes. Class templates differ from function templates in that the compiler cannot deduce the template parameter type(s) for a class template. Instead, as we’ve seen many times, to use a class template we must supply additional information inside angle brackets following the template’s name (§ 3.3, p. 97). That extra information is the list of template arguments to use in place of the template parameters."

But what I think this incorrect: if the the template class has a constructor that takes some dependent type parameters then if I define an object with that constructor, the compiler can deduce the template arguments. e.g:

```
template <typename T>
class Add
{
public:
    Add() = default;
    Add(T const&, T const&);
    T operator ()(T const&, T const&)const;
};

template <typename T>
Add<T>::Add(T const& lhs, T const& rhs){}

template <typename T>
T Add<T>::operator()(T const& lhs, T const& rhs)const
{
    return lhs + rhs;
}

int main()
{

    Add(5, 7); // the compiler can deduce template arguments here.
    std::cout << Add(0, 0)(7, 5) << '\n'; // 12

    Add a(1, 2); // ok
    std::cout << a(5, -1) << '\n'; // 4 ok

    std::cout << "\ndone!\n";
}
```

- So am I right? I've compiled the very code on different c++ standards and works fine.

Comment: The original statement is the compiler needs to be able to deduce it, so you must provide additional information. Usage is additional information. There are cases where the constructor usage doesn't provide this, and you must supply it explicitly. C++ compilers are getting smarter at tracking this usage information, so the strict definition may no longer apply.

Comment: So what's the difference between a template function and a template class as he said? "Class templates differ from function templates in that the compiler cannot deduce the template parameter type(s) for a class template. "

Comment: In the broadest sense they can't, but in specific cases they can. If you had a class with template typed internals that are never exposed, there's no way to deduce it through usage. You must specify them explicitly.

Comment: @tadman: What do you think now about this in the book: "We can now see that that extra information is a list of explicit template arguments that are bound to the template’s parameters. The compiler uses these template arguments to instantiate a specific class from the template. For example, to define a type from our Blob template, we must provide the element type:
Blob<int> ia;                // empty Blob<int>
Blob<int> ia2 = {0,1,2,3,4}; // Blob<int> with five elements"    But If I remove `int` from `ia2` it works fine but not `ia`. It is said it must be explicit.

Comment: The second form is ambiguous without that type information.

Comment: @tadman: But this works form : `Blob ia2{0,1,2,3,4};`.

Comment: Because it has enough information to deduce the type.

Comment: It look like the compilers you tried use a more recent standard that the one on which the book is based. I think that automatic deduction of types for classes is C++ 17.

Comment: @Phil1970 yea you are correct. it works only on c++17 and 20. thank you

Answer (score 1):

that's because [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) in C++17.

new features of C++14/17/20 may not be involved by *C++ Primer*. you can refer to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp to confirm these features.